# CSS Animations not working natively on iOS w/ Cordova port over

Tags: ios, css, cordova, animation

We have a web application that references the [Animate.css](https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/) library. The animations run great in Safari on an iPad, but when we ported the application over to iOS using Cordova they stopped working. Frustratingly, the animations will run on the simulator - but don't do anything when deployed to the actual device.

We have tried several things and we just keep hitting a dead end.

Example animations:

```
@-webkit-keyframes zoomIn {
    0% {
        opacity:0;
        -webkit-transform: scale3d(.3,.3,.3);
        transform:scale3d(.3,.3,.3);
        }
    50% {
        opacity:1;
        }
    }

.exampleElement {
    -webkit-animation:zoomIn 1s forwards;
    animation:zoomIn 1s forwards;
    }
```

Comment: Nothing in the console?

Comment: What do you mean? Can you please clarify? I am not getting any errors if that is what your asking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently iPads running apps with Cordova have an issue with `camelCase` in files and it was not finding the correct css file. Lession learned always be consistent with file naming conventions.